# SSRS Sum Expression with IIF Condition

Tags: reporting-services, sum, ssrs-2012

[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WDXF.png) 
[Here is what My Table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI4UN.png)
My code is supposed to sum the total but it is giving me incorrect results.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Business Risk Reduction", 
Fields!BRRCalcRRPVETC.Value, IIF(Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Major 
Growth" OR Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Contractual Growth" OR 
Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Growth Improvement" OR 
Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Sustenance Efficiency", 
Fields!NPVonETC.Value, NOTHING))).
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?
This code goes in my totals field.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your report, showing the current output and the expected output

Comment: Hi, I have attached 2 samples. One is my table and the other is the result set that has been exported to excel. There are thousands of rows but i removed them in order to get a screen grab. Basically, when i total the second column, (i double check this in excel to make sure it sums up) but it doesnt sum up to be the same as the total row below @niktrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `switch()` instead.

```
=sum(switch(Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Business Risk Reduction", Fields!BRRCalcRRPVETC.Value, Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Major Growth", Fields!NPVonETC.Value, Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Contractual Growth", Fields!NPVonETC.Value, Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Growth Improvement", Fields!NPVonETC.Value, Fields!BusinessDriver.Value = "Sustenance Efficiency", Fields!NPVonETC.Value, 1=1, 0))
```

For more information, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs